# Updating login button of a Navbar in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am working on a DjangoRest application with Vue.js for my frontend.

I have an issue with my navbar component. In my App.vue I have a method to get the `username` and set it to the window.localStorage.

In my Navbar.vue component, I have a conditional rendering if the `username` exists so a `Login` or `Logout` button is displayed.
Everything is working as it should except for one thing: I have to refresh the whole page for my button to switch from login -> logout or loggout -> login.

How should I modify my code for the change to be made automatically by vue? I am using Django for login/logout, is that the issue?

Here is my App.vue:

```
<script>
import NavbarComponent from "@/components/Navbar.vue";
import { apiService } from "@/common/api.service.js";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    NavbarComponent
  },  
  methods: {
    async setUserInfo() {      
      const data = await apiService("/api/user/");
      const requestUser = data["username"];
      window.localStorage.setItem("username", requestUser);          
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.setUserInfo()    
  }  
}
</script>
```

And my navbar componenet:

```
<template>
      {...}
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-2">         
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a v-if="requestUser" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="/accounts/logout/">Se deconnecter</a>
            <a v-else class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="/accounts/login/">Se connecter</a>
          </li>          
        </ul>
      {...} 
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "NavbarComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      requestUser:null }
      },
      methods: {
        setRequestUser() {     
          this.requestUser = window.localStorage.getItem("username"),                      
      },
      created() {
        this.setRequestUser()
      }  
}
</script>
```

Comment: are you using vue-router? or the links redirect to server pages

Comment: it redirects to server pages ("/accounts/logout/" and "/accounts/login/)

Comment: this redirection reloads the page, so i recommend to use vue-router and just use the REST APi to consume the data from server

Comment: can I connect vue-router to django login templates?

Comment: i don't know about django template but i think that you cannot and you should use vue for templating and consume rest api and Json web tokens from the server